# Porque se produce un bucle infinito

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main( ) {
  float numero1, numero2, suma;

  printf( "Introduzca un numero" );
  scanf( "%f", &numero1 );
  while( !scanf( "%f", &numero1 ) )
        {   

                if( !scanf( "%f", &numero1) ) 
                    {
                        printf( "Error: por favor, introduzca un numero\n" ); 
                    }   
                printf("\nintroduzca de nuevo el numero de vectores que desea inmtroducir: ");
                scanf("%f",&numero1);

        }
  printf( "Introduzca otro  numero" );
  scanf( "%f", &numero2 );
    while( !scanf( "%f", &numero2 ) )
        {   

                if( !scanf( "%f", &numero1 ) ) 
                    {
                        printf( "Error: por favor, introduzca un numero\n" ); 
                    }   
                printf("\nintroduzca de nuevo el numero de vectores que desea inmtroducir: ");
                scanf("%f",&numero2);

        }
  suma = numero1 + numero2;

  printf( "%f + %f = %f", numero1, numero2, suma );
  Sleep( 50000 );
}
```

Se me produce un bucle infinito cuando detecta un carácter y no se como evitarlo para hacer que cuando detecte una letra ese bucle se produzca solo una vez y vuelva a revidar la condición.
El bucle esta hecho para que cuando detecte un carácter le pida al usuario que introduzca un numero

Comment: `scanf("%f")` se detiene en el primer caracter que no pueda interpretar como número, y no lo lee. Por tanto hacer otro `scanf("%f")` no servirá de nada, pues se encontrará aún ese carácter que no había sido leido por el anterior, y estarás en las mismas. Puedes leer la entrada del usuario como cadena, y después tratar de convertirla con `sscanf()` (con dos s).

Comment: y puedes aclararme como se convertiria se que esta relacionado con la tabla de valores ASCII pero no me queda muy claro.Para el sscanf se necesita alguna otra biblioteca y en el caso de ser asi cual seria

Comment: `sscanf()` está también en `stdio.h`. He escrito una respuesta explicando su uso (que no tiene nada qué ver con la tabla ASCII, por cierto :-)

Comment: ya esq hoy estuve investigando esto y lei en internet cosas de sacar el codigo ASCII del valor introducido una forma que no me entere mucho pero gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea más simple que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

- Hacemos una función `leer_float()` que reciba la dirección de un `float`, por ejemplo llamándola así: `leer_float(&numero1)`, y  cuya misión sea leer una línea introducida por el usuario (la leerá como cadena para así aceptar cualquier cosa que el usuario escriba), y después intentar traducir el texto que ha leído a `floa`, guardando el resultado en la variable que recibió como parámetro. Retornará 1 si lo ha conseguido con éxito y 0 si no, como `scanf()`, pero a diferencia de `scanf()` al menos habrá consumido la línea tecleada por el usuario, por lo que la próxima vez que la llames leerá una línea nueva.
- Desde el programa principal la llamarías así: `ok = leer_float(&numero)`. Si `ok` vale 1, es que todo ha ido bien, y en `numero` tendrás el valor deseado. Si `ok` vale 0, el valor en `numero` carece de importancia pues tienes que volver a pedir el dato.

Para implementar `leer_float()` usaré `fgets()` que lee una línea completa del teclado como cadena. Para convertirla a `float` usaré `sscanf()` que funciona igual que `scanf()`, sólo que se le pasa como primer parámetro una cadena, y entonces "lee" de esa cadena en vez del teclado. Por lo demás es igual a `scanf()`, tienes que pasarle la cadena de formato (`"%f"`) y la dirección donde quieres dejar el resultado (que será la dirección que recibió `leer_float()` como parámetro). Al igual que `scanf()` te retornará "falso" (`0`) si no ha podido interpretar el dato, por lo que podemos retornar directamente lo que `sscanf()` nos retorne.

El código de `main()` hay que corregirlo. Tal como lo tenías llamabas a `scanf()` muchas veces de forma innecesaria (aparte del problema de que cada vez que lo llamabas volvía a encontrarse con la letra tecleada por el usuario). A la función de lectura del dato sólo hay que llamarla una vez antes de entrar al `while()` y luego sólo hay que llamarla de nuevo si no se pudo leer con éxito, o sea si `ok` es falso.

El código queda así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int leer_float(float *f){
    char buffer[100];

    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    return sscanf(buffer, "%f", f);
}

int main( ) {
  float numero1, numero2, suma;
  int ok;

  printf( "Introduzca un numero" );
  ok = leer_float(&numero1);
  while( !ok )
  {
    printf( "Error: por favor, introduzca un numero\n" );
    printf("\nintroduzca de nuevo el numero de vectores que desea introducir: ");
    ok = leer_float(&numero1);
  }
  printf( "Introduzca otro  numero" );
  ok = leer_float(&numero2 );
  while(!ok)
  {
    printf( "Error: por favor, introduzca un numero\n" );
    printf("\nintroduzca de nuevo el numero de vectores que desea introducir: ");
    ok = leer_float(&numero2);
  }
  suma = numero1 + numero2;
  printf( "%f + %f = %f", numero1, numero2, suma );
}
```